# Prove the convergence of a sequence.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that $$\left\{\frac{{n+k \choose k}}{(n+k)^k} \right\}_{n=1}^\infty \longrightarrow \frac 1{k!}$$ where $${n+k \choose k}=\frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}.$$

**My attempt for the question**

We only have to note that:
\begin{align}
\frac{{n+k \choose k}}{(n+k)^k} &= \frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!(n+k)^k} \\
&=\frac 1{k!} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}{(n+k)^k} \\
&=\frac 1{k!} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}{\underbrace{(n+k)(n+k)\cdots(n+k)}_{k\text{ terms}}} \\
&=\frac 1{k!} \underbrace{ \frac{n+1}{n+k} \cdot \frac{n+2}{n+k} \cdots \frac{n+k}{n+k}}_{k \text{ terms}} 
\end{align}
and
$$\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+k} \cdot \frac{n+2}{n+k} \cdots \frac{n+k}{n+k} = \frac 1{k!} \cdot 1 \cdots 1 = \frac 1{k!}$$

Comment: When asking a question on Math SE, it is better to type out the math instead of uploading an image. For some basic information about writing math at this site see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thank you @JimmyK4542 :) but I look after it :)

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{k!}\frac{n + 1}{n + k} \cdot \frac{n + 2}{n + k} \cdots \frac{n + k}{n + k} = \frac{1}{k!} \cdot 1 \cdots 1$?

Comment: because it is (n+k)!/n!k! :)

Comment: Yes that is right @user46944

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment.  So you meant $\frac{1}{k!}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n+k}\cdot \frac{n + 2}{n + k} \cdots \frac{n + k}{n+k} \to \frac{1}{k!} \cdot 1 \cdots 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes that is right @user46944

Answer (score 1):

For each $p$ with $1 \leq p \leq k$, we have: $\dfrac{n+p}{n+k} = \dfrac{1+\frac{p}{n}}{1+\frac{k}{n}} \rightarrow \dfrac{1+0}{1+0} = 1$. Thus the product: $\dfrac{n+1}{n+k}\cdot \dfrac{n+2}{n+k}...\cdot \dfrac{n+k}{n+k} \rightarrow 1$, and the conclusion follows.

Comment: The my answer is right isnt it? @Dark-chocolate :)

Comment: Your answer is right if you change the $=$ to $\rightarrow$

Comment: Thak you a lot :)